# Nginx http to http redirect 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

i have an app that is exposed at http on port `http://app1.internal.example.com:8080` and https on port `https://app1.internal.example.com:8443`

so i have the 80 and 443 nginx server block to help redirect request coming on the http port to the https port of the app

```
$ curl http://app1.internal.example.com:8080

<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
</body>
</html>

$ curl -IL http://app1.internal.example.com:8080

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2022 00:39:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 220
Connection: close
```

and here is curl on the https port which returns 200

```
$ curl -IL https://app1.internal.example.com:8443

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2022 00:38:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1274335
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

below is my nginx server block for the http to https redirect

how do i fix this error so curl can return 200 on the http request

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name app1.internal.example.com;

    return 301 https://app1.internal.example.com:8443$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name app1.internal.example.com;

    location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port` sounds to me like your assumption that 8080 is HTTP is wrong. Both ports are configured to server HTTPS.

Comment: And TBH, I don't see the relation between this nginx config and your curl requests. There is nothing matching here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed, happened that there was another config file that had port 80 listening on ssl which was causing the error

```
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ssl;

    server_name another-app1.internal.example.com;

    return 301 https://another-app1.internal.example.com:8443$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name another-app1.internal.example.com;

    location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

so i just had to remove the ssl from the port 80 and all seems to work fine now

so here is what that http block should be without the ssl, some older nginx may be `ssl on;`, you have to remove that from port 80 or the http port. Check the whole config files to make sure there is not one missed  and you should be fine

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name another-app1.internal.example.com;

    return 301 https://another-app1.internal.example.com:8443$request_uri;
}

...
...
```